# Solve C*M = N (C,M and N are matrices) where M is known and the structure of N is given in SymPy

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sympy, matrix-multiplication, linear-equation

I have come across this matrix multiplication problem where M is some non-singular 3x3 matrix with known values (i.e M = sympy.Matrix([[1, 0, 0],[0, 2, 0],[0, 0, 3]])) C is a 3x3 matrix to be determined and N is of the following form:
1. The 1st and 3rdrow of N are the same as C (e.g N.row(0)[i] = C.row(0)[i] for 0<=i<=2)
2. The elements in the 2nd row of N are the sum of the corresponding column in M (e.g N.row(1)[1] = sum(M.col(1)))

After searching the web for a way to express this problem as a system of equations I've found nothing. I've been trying to solve this using symbolic matrices and by or by solving three different systems of the form Ax=b each one made of a row from C multiplied by M with b as a column from N such that A = M.T, x = (C.row(i)).T and b = N.

Solving it symbolically resulted in a ridiculous expression that cannot be even be comprehended and I was unable to get a numeric solution from it.

My latest attempt follow:

```py
import sympy as sp
def func(mat=matrix([[1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 2], [1, 4, 5]])):
    c11, c12, c13, c21, c22, c23, c31, c32, c33 = sp.symbols('c11, c12, c13, c21, c22, c23, c31, c32, c33')
    M = mat.T

    b1 = sp.Matrix([[x, y, z]]).T
    b2 = sp.Matrix([[sum(M.col(0)), sum(M.col(1)), sum(M.col(2))]]).T
    b3 = sp.Matrix([[a, b, c]]).T

    M1 = M.col_insert(3, b1)
    M2 = M.col_insert(3, b2)
    M3 = M.col_insert(3, b3)

    C1 = sp.linsolve(M1, (x, y, z))
    C2 = sp.linsolve(M2, (x, y, z))
    C3 = sp.linsolve(M3, (a, b, c))

    return C1, C2, C3
```

Calling this yields the following:

```py
>>> func()
({(x + y - z, -x/2 + 2*y - 3*z/2, -y + z)}, {(-3, -17/2, 6)}, {(a + b - c, -a/2 + 2*b - 3*c/2, -b + c)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't claim I understand your code, but the solution is actually easy to guess: The first and third rows of `C` and `N` must either be left eigenvectors of `M` with eigenvalue `1` which will in the general case not exist or must be zero. The middle row requirement is solved by `C` being all ones and since `M` is nonsingular that's the only solution.

Let's use good old numpy to numerically check this:

```
import numpy as np
M = np.random.random((3, 3))
M
# array([[ 0.39632944,  0.82429087,  0.88705214],
#        [ 0.39092656,  0.63228762,  0.54931835],
#        [ 0.76935833,  0.40833527,  0.46202912]])
C = np.outer((0,1,0),(1,1,1))
C
# array([[0, 0, 0]
#        [1, 1, 1],                                              
#        [0, 0, 0]])
N = np.outer((0,1,0),M.sum(0))
N
# array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 1.55661432,  1.86491377,  1.89839961],
#        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
np.allclose(C @ M , N)
# True
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight